# Sequal Pro: able to enter DB, but unable to read table

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

There are multiple databases on the server, after I enter the 1st db it does show the tables. The weird thing is that I required to get the data from the 3rd db, but after I choose it by the filter, it still shows the tables in 1st db.

I figure out few possible reasons:

1. Setting Sequel Pro configurations incorrectly
2. DB type are not able to show table in Sequel Pro
3. Miss setting some configurations in mysql

Comment: Maybe your database is broken, or something ended up deleting a bunch of files. Or it's fine and you're mistaken about what should be in there. In any case this isn't a programming problem per-se, it sounds more like a tech support issue for MySQL.

Comment: @tadman Thank u for your reply. In fact, it works fine using MYSQL work bench. So the problem has high probability causing by Sequel Pro. Howerver, Sequal Pro are working correctly on other server databases.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in Sequel Pro. Remember, Stack Overflow tries very hard to stay focused on programming-related questions, so this one is outside of that scope.

Comment: @tadman Thank you for your comment, I totally agree with you. I'll try to figure out this question on internet forum that is focusing tools and tech support issues.

Comment: Sounds like quite the mystery. Hope you get it solved!